# Getting duplicate key exception while doing JDBC transaction

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm trying to add designation and its salary using a JDBC transaction.
The problem is this throws an exception about duplicate key.

This is the first time I put some invalid data in salary columns and after that everything is correct. It shows duplicate key exception for designation id
but the designation id is not stored already and not even for first attempt.
The first transaction that is invalid is rolled back, but storing on next time it shows duplicate key exception.

Below is my code:-

```
  public boolean addDesignation(ObservableList nodeList) throws SQLException {
        Connection demo = getConnection();
        demo.setAutoCommit(false);
        Savepoint savePoint = demo.setSavepoint("savePoint");
        try {
        PreparedStatement addDesig =  demo.prepareStatement(
                "INSERT INTO `designation`(`desig_id`,`dept_id`,`desig_name`,`desig_desc`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
        PreparedStatement addSal =  demo.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `salary` "
                + "(`desig_id`, `basic`, `house_rent`, `conveyance`, `medical`, `dearness`,`others_allowances`,"
                + " `income_tax`, `pro_tax`, `emp_state_insu`, `absence_fine`, `others_deductions`, `month`)"
                + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

        addDesig.setString(1 , nodeList.get(0).toString());
        addDesig.setString(2,  nodeList.get(1).toString());
        addDesig.setString(3, nodeList.get(2).toString());
        addDesig.setString(4,  nodeList.get(3).toString());
        addDesig.executeUpdate();

        addSal.setString(1, nodeList.get(0).toString());
        addSal.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(4).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(5).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(4, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(6).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(5, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(7).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(6,Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(8).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(7,Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(9).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(8, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(10).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(9, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(11).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(10, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(12).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(11, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(13).toString()));
        addSal.setInt(12, Integer.parseInt(nodeList.get(14).toString()));
        addSal.setString(13, nodeList.get(15).toString());
        addSal.executeUpdate();
         demo.commit();

         return true;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        demo.rollback(savePoint);

        Logger.getLogger(DatabaseHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

[these are two tables and im trying to add that data in my first attempt failed but not store due roll back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6Y62.png)

Comment: A duplicate key exception means that the data for a key in the database already exists. Given you have not posted a [mcve], we cannot help you because we don't know the definition of your tables and their constraints, nor do we know the data you're trying to insert nor the data already present in your database, nor have you included the full exception stacktrace.

Comment: Also, if you are using MySQL, make sure your tables are InnoDB, MyISAM doesn't support transactions, so rollback nor commit does anything for those table types. The problem might also be that you have only rolled back to the savepoint, but have not yet rolled back or committed the entire transaction. Savepoints are only for rolling back parts of a transaction: the transaction itself also needs to be committed or rolled back.

Comment: i have added the link of table definitions image and these are InnoDB. how transactions are rolled back ??

Comment: Use `demo.rollback()`, and remove your savepoint usage: it doesn't add anything for your code. In any case, don't post pictures, post the actual DDL.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 `INSERT` statements in your code.  
The 1st for `designation` table:

```
"INSERT INTO `designation`(`desig_id`,`dept_id`,`desig_name`,`desig_desc`) VALUES (?,?,?,?)"
```

here it looks like `desig_id` is the primary key (maybe autoincrement in which case you must not supply a value at all).  
Are you sure the value that you supply for this column does not already exist in the table? 
The 2nd for the `salary` table:

```
"INSERT INTO `salary` " + "(`desig_id`, `basic`, `house_rent`, `conveyance`, `medical`, `dearness`,`others_allowances`," + " `income_tax`, `pro_tax`, `emp_state_insu`, `absence_fine`, `others_deductions`, `month`)" + " VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
```

in this case it is not clear since you did not post the `CREATE` statement of the table, which is the primary key.  
So you have to check, if the value (or values if it's a multi column key), violate the uniqueness of the key.

Comment: I have added the link of tables image please check that ... everything is fine if I dont make any mistake while entering data ... if I add some data that causes error than insertion is rolled back but im unable to store that emp_id again

Comment: I don't see a column `emp_id` in any of the 2 tables.

Comment: sorry to say .. its desig_id not emp_id .. I forgot  :)

Comment: In the table `salary` the primary key is `id` for whuch you don't supply a value in your INSERT statement so it must be  autoincrement, so there should be no problem for this insertion. Is the problem in the `designation` table? I see 2 fields that compose the primary key: `id` and `desig_id`. For these you have to check if the values can create duplicates.